# FAKE: Get all projects referenced by a solution file

Tags: f#, f#-fake

How do I get hold of the projects that are referenced by a solution file?

Here I have a concrete use case. I have stolen this target CopyBinaries from ProjectScaffold. It copies the output of the project builds into a separate folder. It is not very choosy and copies the output of every project it finds.

```
Target "CopyBinaries" (fun _ ->
    !! "src/**/*.??proj"
    -- "src/**/*.shproj"
    |> Seq.map (fun f -> 
            ((System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName f) </> "bin/Release", 
             binDir </> (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension f)))
    |> Seq.iter (fun (fromDir, toDir) -> 
            CopyDir toDir fromDir (fun _ -> true))
)
```

What if I want only copy the output of projects which are referenced explicitly in a solution file. I think of something like this:

```
Target "CopyBinaries" (fun _ ->
    !! solutionFile
    |> GetProjectFiles
    |> Seq.map (fun f -> 
            ((System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName f) </> "bin/Release", 
             binDir </> (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension f)))
    |> Seq.iter (fun (fromDir, toDir) -> 
            CopyDir toDir fromDir (fun _ -> true))
)
```

The function GetProjectFiles takes a solution file and extracts the referenced project files.

Is there anything like this hypothetical function in FAKE available?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that I have found which gives this kind of information about solution files out of the box. With a small number of functions, an alternative is possible:

```
let root = directoryInfo "."

let solutionReferences baseDir = baseDir |> filesInDirMatching "*.sln" |> Seq.ofArray

let solutionNames paths = paths |> Seq.map (fun (f:System.IO.FileInfo) -> f.FullName)

let projectsInSolution solutions = solutions |> Seq.collect ReadFile |> Seq.filter (fun line -> line.StartsWith("Project"))

let projectNames projects = projects |> Seq.map (fun (line:string) -> (line.Split [|','|]).[1])

Target "SLN" ( fun () -> root |> solutionReferences |> solutionNames |> projectsInSolution |> projectNames |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s"))
```

This can be consolidated and functions skipped into any grouping you like. You may have already found this out or something else, but it is good that everyone knows there are options. Thank you. Good day.